# UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY webpack@3.5.5 and babel-loader error

Tags: node.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm having trouble installing webpack dev with the following command: `npm i --save-dev webpack`

Webpack is installed succesfully on my computer as `npm i webpack -g` @3.5.5 so no issues here.

When I run `npm i --save-dev webpack` I get a babel-core error reading the following; it will not let me proceed without usinf webpack 1, 2 pr 2.1.0-beta

I cannot get past this and have search stackoverflow and multiple sites.

In my situation, I'm using it with Redux on Windows.

This is my error.

```
`-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY webpack@3.5.5

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\ch
okidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@
1.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"}
)
npm WARN babel-loader@6.2.10 requires a peer of webpack@1 || 2 || ^2.1.0-beta ||
 ^2.2.0-rc but none was installed.
npm WARN prj400r@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN prj400r@1.0.0 No repository field.
```

> Highlighting the babel-core error as being the most problematic. Any workaround?

Comment: Now getting the same error while tring to run express: `npm i --save express`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update babel-loader to version 7.x.x and it should solve your problem. The previous versions required webpack 1 and this support was dropped in version 7

[Release v7.0.0](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader/releases/tag/v7.0.0)